# Chaining DailyCalendar in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, quartz.net

Can I chain DailyCalendar in Quartz.NET ?
I tried to use this code

```
var one = new DailyCalendar("16:54", "16:55");
var two = new DailyCalendar(one, "16:57", "16:58");
_scheduler.AddCalendar(jp.JobName + "Calendar",two, true, true);

trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithIdentity(jp.TriggerName, jp.TriggerGroup)
                   .StartNow()
                   .WithCronSchedule(jp.CronExpr, x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
                   .ModifiedByCalendar(jp.JobName + "Calendar")
                   .Build();
```

My cron expression looks like "0 0/1 * * * ?".

Only the first interval (one) working, job not fired in this interval as expected, but job fired in second interval (two). Is there a problem with DailyCalendar chaining?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine on my dev environment- what does your cron expression look like?